# Extract pokemons that start with a and b

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Given an object with an array of pokemons, i need to extract only the ones that start with a and put them into an array. And the same with the ones that start with b.
These arrays will be inside an onject. something like this. how would you do it? (using Javascript)
I tried many ways with for each and split methods.

```
*//const namePokemons {
// “a”: []
// “b”: []
//}

const pokemonMock = {
    "count": 1118,
    "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=300&limit=100",
    "previous": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=100&limit=100",
    "results": [
      {
        "name": "unown",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/201/"
      },
      {
        "name": "wobbuffet",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/202/"
      },
      {
        "name": "girafarig",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/203/"
      },
      {
        "name": "pineco",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/204/"
      },
      {
        "name": "forretress",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/205/"
      },
      {
        "name": "dunsparce",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/206/"
      },
      {
        "name": "gligar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/207/"
      },
      {
        "name": "steelix",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/208/"
      },
      {
        "name": "snubbull",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/209/"
      },
      {
        "name": "granbull",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/210/"
      },
      {
        "name": "qwilfish",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/211/"
      },
      {
        "name": "scizor",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/212/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shuckle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/213/"
      },
      {
        "name": "heracross",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/214/"
      },
      {
        "name": "sneasel",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/215/"
      },
      {
        "name": "teddiursa",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/216/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ursaring",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/217/"
      },
      {
        "name": "slugma",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/218/"
      },
      {
        "name": "magcargo",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/219/"
      },
      {
        "name": "swinub",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/220/"
      },
      {
        "name": "piloswine",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/221/"
      },
      {
        "name": "corsola",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/222/"
      },
      {
        "name": "remoraid",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/223/"
      },
      {
        "name": "octillery",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/224/"
      },
      {
        "name": "delibird",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/225/"
      },
      {
        "name": "mantine",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/226/"
      },
      {
        "name": "skarmory",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/227/"
      },
      {
        "name": "houndour",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/228/"
      },
      {
        "name": "houndoom",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/229/"
      },
      {
        "name": "kingdra",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/230/"
      },
      {
        "name": "phanpy",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/231/"
      },
      {
        "name": "donphan",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/232/"
      },
      {
        "name": "porygon2",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/233/"
      },
      {
        "name": "stantler",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/234/"
      },
      {
        "name": "smeargle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/235/"
      },
      {
        "name": "tyrogue",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/236/"
      },
      {
        "name": "hitmontop",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/237/"
      },
      {
        "name": "smoochum",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/238/"
      },
      {
        "name": "elekid",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/239/"
      },
      {
        "name": "magby",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/240/"
      },
      {
        "name": "miltank",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/241/"
      },
      {
        "name": "blissey",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/242/"
      },
      {
        "name": "raikou",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/243/"
      },
      {
        "name": "entei",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/244/"
      },
      {
        "name": "suicune",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/245/"
      },
      {
        "name": "larvitar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/246/"
      },
      {
        "name": "pupitar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/247/"
      },
      {
        "name": "tyranitar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/248/"
      },
      {
        "name": "lugia",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/249/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ho-oh",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/250/"
      },
      {
        "name": "celebi",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/251/"
      },
      {
        "name": "treecko",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/252/"
      },
      {
        "name": "grovyle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/253/"
      },
      {
        "name": "sceptile",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/254/"
      },
      {
        "name": "torchic",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/255/"
      },
      {
        "name": "combusken",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/256/"
      },
      {
        "name": "blaziken",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/257/"
      },
      {
        "name": "mudkip",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/258/"
      },
      {
        "name": "marshtomp",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/259/"
      },
      {
        "name": "swampert",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/260/"
      },
      {
        "name": "poochyena",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/261/"
      },
      {
        "name": "mightyena",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/262/"
      },
      {
        "name": "zigzagoon",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/263/"
      },
      {
        "name": "linoone",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/264/"
      },
      {
        "name": "wurmple",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/265/"
      },
      {
        "name": "silcoon",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/266/"
      },
      {
        "name": "beautifly",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/267/"
      },
      {
        "name": "cascoon",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/268/"
      },
      {
        "name": "dustox",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/269/"
      },
      {
        "name": "lotad",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/270/"
      },
      {
        "name": "lombre",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/271/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ludicolo",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/272/"
      },
      {
        "name": "seedot",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/273/"
      },
      {
        "name": "nuzleaf",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/274/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shiftry",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/275/"
      },
      {
        "name": "taillow",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/276/"
      },
      {
        "name": "swellow",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/277/"
      },
      {
        "name": "wingull",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/278/"
      },
      {
        "name": "pelipper",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/279/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ralts",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/280/"
      },
      {
        "name": "kirlia",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/281/"
      },
      {
        "name": "gardevoir",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/282/"
      },
      {
        "name": "surskit",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/283/"
      },
      {
        "name": "masquerain",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/284/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shroomish",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/285/"
      },
      {
        "name": "breloom",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/286/"
      },
      {
        "name": "slakoth",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/287/"
      },
      {
        "name": "vigoroth",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/288/"
      },
      {
        "name": "slaking",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/289/"
      },
      {
        "name": "nincada",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/290/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ninjask",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/291/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shedinja",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/292/"
      },
      {
        "name": "whismur",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/293/"
      },
      {
        "name": "loudred",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/294/"
      },
      {
        "name": "exploud",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/295/"
      },
      {
        "name": "makuhita",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/296/"
      },
      {
        "name": "hariyama",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/297/"
      },
      {
        "name": "azurill",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/298/"
      },
      {
        "name": "nosepass",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/299/"
      },
      {
        "name": "skitty",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/300/"
      }
    ]
  }*
```

Comment: *"I tried many ways"* - Is there a reason you didn't include any of those attempts in your question? Stackoverflow is not a coding service; you're expected to make an effort (which is sounds like you did), and if you can post what you've tried, we'll be more willing and able to help you debug your approach or suggest alternatives.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## FILTER FUNCTION

In your case, you should consider using .filter JS method to filter those elements that start with "a".

If you want both pokemons that starts with "a" or "b":

```js
  let pokemonStartingWithAorB = pokemonMock.results.filter(function(pokemon){
    if(pokemon.name.startsWith("a") || pokemon.name.startsWith('b')){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

If you want only pokemons that start with "a":

```js
let pokemonStartingWithA = pokemonMock.results.filter(pokemon => pokemon.name.startsWith('a'));
```

The reference to the filter function: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the array, get the name and verify if it starts with a or b, if it does add to desired array.

```js
const pokemonMock = {
    "count": 1118,
    "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=300&limit=100",
    "previous": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=100&limit=100",
    "results": [
      {
        "name": "unown",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/201/"
      },
      {
        "name": "wobbuffet",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/202/"
      },
      {
        "name": "girafarig",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/203/"
      },
      {
        "name": "pineco",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/204/"
      },
      {
        "name": "forretress",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/205/"
      },
      {
        "name": "dunsparce",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/206/"
      },
      {
        "name": "gligar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/207/"
      },
      {
        "name": "steelix",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/208/"
      },
      {
        "name": "snubbull",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/209/"
      },
      {
        "name": "granbull",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/210/"
      },
      {
        "name": "qwilfish",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/211/"
      },
      {
        "name": "scizor",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/212/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shuckle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/213/"
      },
      {
        "name": "heracross",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/214/"
      },
      {
        "name": "sneasel",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/215/"
      },
      {
        "name": "teddiursa",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/216/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ursaring",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/217/"
      },
      {
        "name": "slugma",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/218/"
      },
      {
        "name": "magcargo",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/219/"
      },
      {
        "name": "swinub",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/220/"
      },
      {
        "name": "piloswine",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/221/"
      },
      {
        "name": "corsola",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/222/"
      },
      {
        "name": "remoraid",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/223/"
      },
      {
        "name": "octillery",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/224/"
      },
      {
        "name": "delibird",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/225/"
      },
      {
        "name": "mantine",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/226/"
      },
      {
        "name": "skarmory",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/227/"
      },
      {
        "name": "houndour",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/228/"
      },
      {
        "name": "houndoom",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/229/"
      },
      {
        "name": "kingdra",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/230/"
      },
      {
        "name": "phanpy",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/231/"
      },
      {
        "name": "donphan",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/232/"
      },
      {
        "name": "porygon2",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/233/"
      },
      {
        "name": "stantler",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/234/"
      },
      {
        "name": "smeargle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/235/"
      },
      {
        "name": "tyrogue",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/236/"
      },
      {
        "name": "hitmontop",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/237/"
      },
      {
        "name": "smoochum",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/238/"
      },
      {
        "name": "elekid",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/239/"
      },
      {
        "name": "magby",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/240/"
      },
      {
        "name": "miltank",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/241/"
      },
      {
        "name": "blissey",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/242/"
      },
      {
        "name": "raikou",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/243/"
      },
      {
        "name": "entei",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/244/"
      },
      {
        "name": "suicune",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/245/"
      },
      {
        "name": "larvitar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/246/"
      },
      {
        "name": "pupitar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/247/"
      },
      {
        "name": "tyranitar",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/248/"
      },
      {
        "name": "lugia",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/249/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ho-oh",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/250/"
      },
      {
        "name": "celebi",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/251/"
      },
      {
        "name": "treecko",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/252/"
      },
      {
        "name": "grovyle",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/253/"
      },
      {
        "name": "sceptile",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/254/"
      },
      {
        "name": "torchic",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/255/"
      },
      {
        "name": "combusken",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/256/"
      },
      {
        "name": "blaziken",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/257/"
      },
      {
        "name": "mudkip",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/258/"
      },
      {
        "name": "marshtomp",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/259/"
      },
      {
        "name": "swampert",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/260/"
      },
      {
        "name": "poochyena",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/261/"
      },
      {
        "name": "mightyena",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/262/"
      },
      {
        "name": "zigzagoon",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/263/"
      },
      {
        "name": "linoone",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/264/"
      },
      {
        "name": "wurmple",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/265/"
      },
      {
        "name": "silcoon",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/266/"
      },
      {
        "name": "beautifly",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/267/"
      },
      {
        "name": "cascoon",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/268/"
      },
      {
        "name": "dustox",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/269/"
      },
      {
        "name": "lotad",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/270/"
      },
      {
        "name": "lombre",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/271/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ludicolo",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/272/"
      },
      {
        "name": "seedot",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/273/"
      },
      {
        "name": "nuzleaf",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/274/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shiftry",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/275/"
      },
      {
        "name": "taillow",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/276/"
      },
      {
        "name": "swellow",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/277/"
      },
      {
        "name": "wingull",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/278/"
      },
      {
        "name": "pelipper",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/279/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ralts",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/280/"
      },
      {
        "name": "kirlia",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/281/"
      },
      {
        "name": "gardevoir",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/282/"
      },
      {
        "name": "surskit",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/283/"
      },
      {
        "name": "masquerain",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/284/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shroomish",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/285/"
      },
      {
        "name": "breloom",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/286/"
      },
      {
        "name": "slakoth",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/287/"
      },
      {
        "name": "vigoroth",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/288/"
      },
      {
        "name": "slaking",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/289/"
      },
      {
        "name": "nincada",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/290/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ninjask",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/291/"
      },
      {
        "name": "shedinja",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/292/"
      },
      {
        "name": "whismur",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/293/"
      },
      {
        "name": "loudred",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/294/"
      },
      {
        "name": "exploud",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/295/"
      },
      {
        "name": "makuhita",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/296/"
      },
      {
        "name": "hariyama",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/297/"
      },
      {
        "name": "azurill",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/298/"
      },
      {
        "name": "nosepass",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/299/"
      },
      {
        "name": "skitty",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/300/"
      }
    ]
  }
  
const namePokemons = {
    "a": [],
  "b": []
};

pokemonMock.results.forEach(element => {
    let name = element.name;
  if(name.charAt(0) == 'a') {
    namePokemons.a.push(name);
  }
  if(name.charAt(0) == 'b') {
    namePokemons.b.push(name);
  }
 });
 
 console.log(`name pokemons start with "a": ${namePokemons.a}`);
 console.log(`name pokemons start with "b": ${namePokemons.b}`);
```